# How to create "check all" JavaScript method

Tags: javascript

I'm interested how I can create a button which calls JavaScript method which makes all check boxes in h:table(simple html table) all to be checked? And how I can make all check boxes into the table unchecked again with JavaScript method? Can you show me some code snipped or working example, please?

Answer (score 6):

1. Create a button
2. [Add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener) to the button. In the listener, do:

   1. select the table element where you want to check all boxes, e.g. [by Id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)
   2. Use [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) for input elements
   3. Loop over the list of inputs:

      - If the type of [the input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) is "checkbox", set its `checked` property to `true`

Comment: +1 for teaching-to-fish versus spoon-feeding. You might also mention `querySelectorAll()`

Answer (score 2):

```
<h:table>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
</h:table>

<script>
    function checkBoxesForMe( checkBoxesOn )
    {
        var table = document.getElementsByTagName( 'h:table' )[ 0 ]
        var inputs = table.getElementsByTagName( 'input' )

        for( var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++ )
        {
            if( inputs[ i ].type == 'checkbox' ) 
            {
                if( checkBoxesOn )
                    inputs[ i ].setAttribute( 'checked', true )
                else
                    inputs[ i ].removeAttribute( 'checked' )
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What will happen if I switch all the checkboxes, and switch between pages(pagination) are they going to be all checked?

Comment: `inputs[i].checked = checkBoxesOn;` would be both shorter and more appropriate than `.setAttribute()` and `.removeAttribute()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following functions should be self explanatory:

```
function checkboxesCheckAll() {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var i = boxes.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (boxes[i].type == 'checkbox') boxes[i].checked = true;
  }
}

function checkboxesCheckNone() {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var i = boxes.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (boxes[i].type == 'checkbox') boxes[i].checked = false;
  }
}

function checkboxesCheckToggle() {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  var i = boxes.length;
  while (i--) {
    if (boxes[i].type == 'checkbox') boxes[i].checked = !boxes[i].checked;
  }
}
```

Or you could write it as one function and pass a parameter to check, unckeck or toggle them.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using jQuery very easily:

check all

```
$("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", true);
```

uncheck all:

```
$("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);
```

So with the button:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a">a<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="b">b<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="c">c<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="d">d<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="e">e<br/>
<button data-action="check">Check All</button>
<button data-action="uncheck">Uncheck All</button>​

$('button').click(function() {
    $("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", $(this).data('action') === 'check');
})​
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bn386/

Comment: Would you show me how this can be written like a method, please? And one more question: What will happen if I switch pages(pagination)?

Comment: I hope the above code works for you. Not sue what you mean by "What will happen if I switch pages(pagination)"

Comment: For example if I have a table with pages, like this http://datatables.net/ What will happen if I use your JavaScript method to select all checkboxes into the table and then I switch to page 2 of the table? Maybe the checkboxes into the second page won't be selected or they will be?

Comment: MOst likely they will not be. The code I provided works on all checkboxes in the DOM at the moment it is run. Pagination very often changes the DOM and adds stuff to it. If that stuff contains checkboxes then they will not be checked.

Comment: If datatables.net does not provide a "select all" function in their API, then I think you're out of luck.